# svc-less wcf service and metadata

Tags: c#, wcf

I've tried to create svc-less wcf service. Service works, but no metadata are genereted.
How can I return service metadata back?

Comment: Can you please post your binding information?

Comment: I guess no need to specify binding information, the problem was that I used WebServiceHostFactory, that disable metadata generation functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a meta data endpoint to your service generation in the code?

```
 ServiceMetadataBehavior  smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();

    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;

    smb.HttpGetUrl = new Uri(EndPointAddress);

    Host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
```

Or using config file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="yourServiceName" 
               behaviorConfiguration="yourBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "yourBaseAddress" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address ="..." 
                  binding="httpBinding" 
                  contract="..." />

        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="yourBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>        
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Not sure, where in the code can I do that, I hosted wcf service in IIS. I am newbie regarding WCF technology =)